# When trying to remove an item from array errors

Tags: arrays, processing, khan-academy

So when writing a game on [Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/escape/6556810072817664) When I try to remove a bullet from the array I run into the error "Object does not support method splice" I have been checking my code for hours and have not found out why it does not work. Ideas?

EDIT: The code used to remove a bullet is `bullets[i].splice(i,1);` and that is what errors out my code.

MVCE:

```
var bullets = [];

var bullet= function(x,y,blah)
{
    //code that is not important here
};

bullets.push(bullet(0,0,30));
for(var I = 0; I < bullets.length; I++){
if(bulletRemove){
bullets[I].splice(i,1)
}
}
```

Comment: post your code here. we don't go "outside" to look at it.

Comment: Can you please post your code here? The code you linked doesn't make a ton of sense- every call to the `splice()` function is commented out, so I'm not sure how your code can generate the error you're talking about.

Comment: Just found out that I could select all then hit Ctrl+k to indent

Comment: exactly WHERE in all that is the error occurring? we're not going to count down 548 lines...

Comment: Go to the very bottom draw function. Scroll up a little. You will see a if statement saying

Comment: if(rectCircleCollide(player.x,player.y,bSize,bSize,null,bullets[i].giveCords("x"),bullets[i].giveCords("y"),10)){

Comment: that is the error spot

Comment: @MarcB sorry about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a variable named `bullets`:

```javascript
var bullets = [];
```

(Side note: Why is there a random curly bracket right before this line?)

This `bullets` variable is an array. It holds instances of the `Bullet` class:

```javascript
bullets.push(new Bullet(x, y, 10, player.x+bSize/2, player.y+bSize/2));
```

You can use the array to access a `Bullet` at a particular index, and then you can call functions of the `Bullet` class on that instance:

```javascript
bullets[i].move();
```

You can also call the `splice()` function on the array itself:

```javascript
bullets.splice(i,1);
```

However, you **can't** call the `splice()` function on a particular `Bullet` instance!

```javascript
bullets[i].splice(i,1);
```

This line is taking an instance of `Bullet` from the `i` index of the `bullets` array, and then trying to call the `splice()` function from the `Bullet` class. But the `Bullet` class doesn't have a `splice()` function! This is what's causing the error.

Instead, you probably meant to call it on the array itself:

```javascript
bullets.splice(i,1);
```

In the future, **please please please** try to narrow your problem down before posting a question. Try to post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead of your entire project. You could have put together an example program that used just a few lines to create a hard-coded array and used that to demonstrate your problem. Chances are you would have found the problem yourself in the process of creating the MCVE!

Comment: I will work on making MCVE in the future. Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: Also the curly brackets are used on khan academy to group code. so if I have a section of code about collisions (as I do) and I do the following { "collision code here" } and put functions in the collision code I can click on a arrow by the first bracket and compress all the code into one line so you just see {<=>} instead of a lot of code. It helps organize the code into sections.

Comment: @ChristopherPeart Fair enough about the curly brackets. I might argue that these sections should be split into their own functions then. Using random curly brackets seems a bit strange, mostly because it's not obvious to me what the scope of variables defined inside these blocks are. Seems like a recipe for more bugs.

Comment: If you would like go to this link https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/escape/6556810072817664 that I have my program and you can see what I mean better

Comment: @ChristopherPeart I'm behind a firewall that blocks that site (this is why we ask for code in the question itself, it's not **just** us being lazy), but I understand what you mean. But the scope of the variable is external to the block, which is again not very obvious to me. [Quote from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block): "Although "standalone" blocks are valid syntax, you do not want to use standalone blocks in JavaScript, because they don't do what you think they do, if you think they do anything like such blocks in C or Java."

Comment: Huh. I just use them to group code so I can find the code I need faster. I don't try to use them to have local variables.

Comment: @ChristopherPeart If that's your preference, I say go for it. I think it makes your code slightly harder for other people to read, and splitting it into functions would be a better way to organize your code. But go with whatever fits into your head the best.

Comment: Looking back at old answers I realized how good of an idea that is. People like you keep SO alive (and me too)

Comment: @ChristopherPeart Thanks, that's awesome to hear!